# How to fix the following QuoteChar error while using Python to load data in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I was writing a code, to load data to MySQL using Python. This code helps users to directly load the data to MySQL without opening the file. As the data size are pretty big they take time to open up.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import string
import csv
import mysql.connector
import re


# In[2]:


mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password",autocommit=True)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


# In[3]:


sql_str=''
sql_str1=''
field_name=[]
line=1
file_name=input("\nFile name with extension:")
delimiter_=input('\nDelimiter used:')
textquali=input('\nText Qualifier used Press Enter if no qualifier:')


# In[4]:


mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src")
#r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv"
#re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row)
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_name,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore'), delimiter=delimiter_,quotechar=textquali)
rowHeaders = reader.fieldnames
print(rowHeaders)
for i in rowHeaders:
    field_name.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', i))
#print(field_name)
#print(f'''create table rd.data_with_header ( {" varchar(100), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))''')
sql_str=f'''create table rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src ( {" varchar(250), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))'''
mycursor.execute(sql_str)
for row in reader:
    line=line+1
    sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')"""
    print(line)
    print(sql_str1)
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1)
    print("Loaded")
```

This is the requirement by the user. Therefore cant do much about it. The issue I am facing is even though the print statement to check if the code is correct or not is showing the correct sql code is running but still getting a Syntax error for SQL. I can only show with an example as I cannot show client data. The Delimiter is comma and Quote Character is Double Quotes " ,

```
So my print is showing the correct header and sql code:
['Id', 'L_Id', 'Combination','Name']
insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('1','111,2 Sam'G Revo','22-3','JK')

But the error getting generated is :
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'G Revo','22-3'' at line 1
```

As per my understanding this maybe due to the single quotation being used. Can someone guide with a different approach. Please help. (Also, I am new to Python).

Comment: `insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('1','111,2 Sam\'G Revo','22-3','JK')`

Comment: Hi, 
I am not supposed to meddle with the client data :) .

Comment: Python **must** process user's input. For example, replace `'` with `\'` before action.

Comment: Is there a way i can implement that in the code I prepared? I dont want python to process the the whole dataset and replace all the ' to \

Comment: If you have names like  Sam'G Revo where there is a single quote in the name then you are going to have to write code to detect them and escape them - or have the client do so..

Comment: *I dont want python to process the the whole dataset and replace all the ' to \* Not dataset. Single value, after user inputs it but before sending it to MySQL for storing in a table.

Comment: Hi guys, can you let me know what syntax to use to replace the ' character?  
sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')"""
I tried few methods but they dont seem to work.